# Remove string after last slash in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a problem with removing everything after the last slash of URL in Elixir. For instance, I have URL:

`http://localhost:4000/admins/new`

I wanna change it to:

`http://localhost:4000/admins`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```rb
Regex.replace(~r{/[^/]+$}, "http://localhost:4000/admins/new", "")
```

Output:

```rb
"http://localhost:4000/admins"
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way would probably be to use [`URI.parse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#parse/1)

```rb
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:4000/admins/new")

%URI{uri |
  path:
    uri.path
    |> String.split("/")
    |> Enum.slice(0..-2)
    |> Enum.join("/")
}
|> URI.to_string()

#⇒ "http://localhost:4000/admins"
```